# change time grayed out in windows server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, time-synchronization

I have Windows server 2016 joined to domain. I want to put back date in the server. But the option for changing date and time is grayed out. It has a message saying "Some settings are hidden or managed by your organisation".

When I change the date from server manager->local servers, the date set back to  current date automatically.

From Domain Group policy I have given my self permission to change time. But still the option is grayed out.

Appreciate your input here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and the issue wasn't related to policy. Only changing it in the Local Server section of the Server Manager worked. See this article:
https://www.dtonias.com/set-time-date-timezone-settings-server-2016/

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. When the link breaks, your answer becomes worthless later even if the linked material answered the question. Please include at least a summary so the answer can stand on its own. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"Some settings are hidden or managed by your organisation" clearly indicates that settings locked down by some policy (local or domain). Try to use Resultant Set of Policy (rsop.msc) or gpresult command line tool to see which exact policy blocks these settings.